# Conditional input options/validation in React Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, react-hook-form

I’m new to react and I’m connecting a react front end to a flask backend. I’m in a group project but I’ve been somehow responsible for 90% of the work. I’ve implemented the fields with MUI but I’m flexible and prefer working over appearance.

I made a form with react-form-hooks and tried to implement a custom range slider (I’m sorry that it’s not all broken out to components and is mainly single file). I’m new to React, JS and TSX (there’s a sandbox at the bottom of the post).

*Side-note: the form is loading pretty slow right now, any tips on improving performance would be greatly appreciated. (:
(Actually at this point appreciative for any ideas and open to feedback).

[Advanced Search Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4rq8.png)

What I am trying to achieve:

I am trying to take input as a range of values from 0 to 100 in a form. The values can be passed as [0,100] on default or if they are updated, on pressing submit the current values ([min, max]) of their state would be submitted. The information would be passed as a json response to an api backend through a post request.

I found some options online on implementing a range slider with react-hooks-form but could not get any of them to work unfortunately. Could someone please help me implement the range slider (I will need to use 3 of them in my form)?

If this is not possible, could you please assist with one of the following alternatives:

Option 1: Setting up a select box/combo-box that does the following:

Provides the user a max or min option based off the corresponding max/min option. I.e. if there is no input in either the Max or Min select/combo-box: Then both boxes would have 0-100 as the possible range of values. If the value of one box was touched: then the second select/combo fields values would be of the corresponding remainder of the range.

E.g. If I selected 70 for my minimum value my other select/combo would provide for me to either leave it blank, or give me the options 70 to 100. Or if I selected 82 for the max input field- the select for min would only allow me to use 0 to 82 for my min or leave it blank.

Option 2:
Text input fields with the same validation schema as above that would become an error state if the user entered something like:
artist-rating min: 40
artist-rating max: 20

Here is the sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/advanced-search-form-forked-0lhgrv

Comment: Please be more precise on WHAT you are trying to achieve more then HOW. You want a min-max controlled slider ? Wht the mui slider range is not working for you ?

Comment: @CesarePolonara I updated the post to hopefully clarify my intentions. Thank you for the feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating the post.
You problem is that `Mui Slider` Component, doesn't take the default input props, so you can't spread the `register` method returned by `react-hook-form` since it returns the default `value` and `onChange` props.

But `react-hook-form` is a great library and it already addressed the integration with the main react UI libs: https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingwithUIlibraries

I implemented a basic example here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-silence-9qlfbj?file=/src/App.js
They expose quite extensive and clear APIs, take your time to study them if you plan to use it as your form management library.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I did look at the documentation (actually was the first thing I did) and I think I became more confused because I am new to this. I did try your example but it's only registering one value instead of two (the min value and the max value).

Comment: It's an array of two values, min and max.